# How to filter out fields with custom attribute in asp.net Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, action-filter

I have a working model that i use within my application.  I want to expose some of this data via a public API, but i have fields that I don't want to return for general consumption.
One laborious way to do this is to create a seperate model and create use automapper to map my output to create some a series of DTOs.

What i'd like to do is annotate my model with a custom attribute and then somehow have some sort of extension method or web API actionfilter filter out the annotated fields at runtime before sending JSON to the client.  I can't use JsonIgnore because i need those fields for operations within my application.

Can someone give me an overview on how I would do this?

thanks in advance

**Edit**

So I am thinking I can use the newtonsoft ShouldSerialize property , however I'm at a loss in regards to finding an elegant way of setting a condition that triggers this.   I have a complex model and I would think at runtime I would need to reflect the entire output, detect any class within a certain namespace, and set some value that causes ShouldSerialize to return true

Comment: Will [JsonIgnore] help?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#explicit-expansion

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely want to avoid DTOs and `[JsonIgnore]`, and really want to use a custom attribute, you would probably have to use some reflection. I'll present a solution which is far from being the best option, but it can give you some ideas.

First, create a custom attribute to mark the properties of your model which aren't supposed to be displayed via your public API:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
class DontSendInPublicApiAttribute : Attribute { }
```

You'd have to create a method for "erasing" the data on the object's properties which you do not want to display.

```
public static void RemoveSecretData(object obj)
{
    // Retrieve all public instance properties defined for the object's type and marked with [DontSendInPublicApi]
    var propertiesToHide = obj.GetType()
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
        .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<DontSendInPublicApiAttribute>() != null);

    foreach (var prop in propertiesToHide)
    {
        // Set all of these properties in the given object to their default values.
        // VALUE TYPES (ints, chars, doubles, etc.) will be set to default(TheTypeOfValue), by calling Activator.CreateInstance(TheTypeOfValue).
        // REFERENCE TYPES will simply be set to null.
        var propertyType = prop.PropertyType;
        if (propertyType.IsValueType)
            prop.SetValue(obj, Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType));
        else
            prop.SetValue(obj, null);
    }
}
```

Then apply the attribute to any fields in your model which you wish to hide:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [DontSendInPublicApi]
    public string Occupation { get; set; }
    [DontSendInPublicApi]
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}
```

And here's an example of how to call it:

```
var person = new Person() { Name = "John", Age = 29, Occupation = "Engineer", Salary = 200000 };
RemoveSecretData(person);
```

After `RemoveSecretData(person)` has been executed, you'll have the `Occupation` and `Salary` properties of the `person` object set to `null` and `0`, respectivelly.

Notes about this solution:

- Works only on properties. You'd have to modify the `RemoveSecretData()` method to also work with fields, if necessary.
- Doesn't recursivelly access the objects graph. If your object references another object with some property marked with `[DontSendInPublicApi]`, this property will not be hidden. You'd have to modify the `RemoveSecretData()` method to perform recursive calls on deeper objects, if necessary. Watch out for circular references if you plan on doing so.
- Hidden properties will still be shown on output JSON, but **value-typed** properties will always present a value of `0` (zero) and **reference-typed** properties will always present a value of `null`.

Comment: Thank you this is along the lines of what I was thinking but I need the entire property removed. I'm thinking at this point of just returning a dictionary since it all gets serialized into JSON anyways.